# Finding out the financial Statements

Tags: finance, stock

Hello It's my first time using Stack overflow so I'm just wondering if there is any thing can help me find the financial statements for companies all I want is Assets Liabilities Equity Return on Asset ROE Dividends PE Volatility and Beta
It's very basic I know...
I tried to find stuff online but couldn't find any things that I need and I need to cut the calculation time and searching. Thanks!

Comment: What is your Question? You are supposed to ask _one_ question for _one_ specific problem with an example of the problem.

Comment: How can i get them from a website or anything?